# Design the transition function

Tags: automata, turing-machines

I need to design a Turing Machine that accepts the (context-free) language: $L(M)=\{0^{n}1^{n+1}: n\ge1$}.

$$Q=\{q_0,q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4\} ,Σ = \{0,1\}, Γ =\{0,1,X,Y,B\}, F=\{q_4\}$$

X- processed 0
Y- processed 1
B- blank
P-move right
L-move left
So far I've succeeded to create a table for languages $\{0^n1^n\}$(without the red entry) and $\{0^n1^k:k\ge n\}$.

[image: "P" means the right side]

What should it look for case in which there is minimal superiority of "1's"?

@EDIT

Meanwhile I've finally hit on an idea for **L(M)**

[image]Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

If you have managed to solve $0^n1^n$ then $q_4$ should simply proceed to the rightmost bit you haven't processed yet and verify that it's a 1 and that there is nothing following it.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I can't put it into effect. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Could you quickly comment on what the semantics for X, Y and B are?  I guess B is blank, X is a processed 0 and Y a processed 1?  Does P mean 'move right'?

Comment: You've guessed right. Question updated.

Comment: Let's say that the invariant is such that your tape looks like this: $BXXX0000YYY11111B$ (just an example).  In the end, your tape must look like this: $BXXXXXXXYYYYYYY1B$.  Considering this, it should be straight forward to go right of all $X$'s, all $Y$'s and then verify that the next symbol is a 1 and then a $B$.  I'm not going to decode your transition table (probably no one else either) so you will have to explain your algorithm (or at least idea) in a clear and precise, yet easy to understand readable English.

Comment: @PålGD, totally agree. This is programming, and that is convincing your fellow humans that it works in _all_ cases, not asking the computer to calculate a few results and concluding that if they look OK it will be OK in all cases.